# Proof that pre-image of sigma algebra is sigma-algebra, complement

Tags: measure-theory

I have one more quetion regarding the proof that the pre-image of a sigma-algebra is a sigma-algebra too.

Given are again sets X,Y and a map f: X $\rightarrow$ Y, if B is a $\sigma$-algebra on Y, then we shall show that

$\mathcal{A} = \{f^{-1}(E) ; E \in B\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on X.

Now I want to show that for $A \in \mathcal{A}$ it follows that $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$.

Well first we can show that $f^{-1}(E)^c = f^{-1}(E^c)$, since $f^{-1}(E)^c = \{x \in X; f(x) \neq E\} = \{x \in X; f(x) = E^c\} = f^{-1}(E^c)$. And $f^{-1}(E^c)$ is in $\mathcal{A}$ since B is a sigma-algebra.

How can I show now that $A^c \in \mathcal{A} = f^{-1}(E^c)$ ?

Comment: I think you mean $f(x) \in E$ and $f(x) \notin E^c$ rather than $f(x) = E$ and $f(x) = E^c$ in the second-to-last paragraph.

Comment: true..I got a bit confused at some point. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t see the problem: you have the necessary pieces. Let $A\in\mathcal{A}$; then $A=f^{-1}[E]$ for some $E\in\mathcal{B}$, and $$A^c=\left(f^{-1}[E]\right)^c=f^{-1}\left[E^c\right]\in\mathcal{A}\;,$$ since $E^c\in\mathcal{B}$.

Your argument that $\left(f^{-1}[E]\right)^c=f^{-1}\left[E^c\right]$ needs a little repair, but I suspect that the errors are typographical rather than substantial.

Comment: @user62487: You’re welcome!